# angular 10+. mouseclick event always continuously fire the angular detect changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I binding any event on a elements in component html page, the component continuously detect changes when the element event fired .although i had set the component detect change mode be OnPush.I try build a simple project and no dependency except the angular core library.

the code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-tour-of-heroes';


  onClick() {
    console.log("click");
  }

  value(){
    console.log("detect fired");
    return "value";
  }

}


app.component.html code

<button type="button" (click)="onClick()">button</button>
{{value()}}
```

browser console output when I clicked the button:

> click
>
> detect fired

when I clicked the button and output 'detect fired' even there no any code calling the method :`ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`

thank!

I thought the value() method shouldn't be executed when I click the button  until I execute `changedetectionref.markForCheck()`

Comment: why are you required to use `changeDetection`?

Comment: To know "what are changed" (if you don't use  ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush), Angular check the interpolation variables and getter in .html. If you use a function inside an interpolation in  .html, Angular need execute to know if "some are changed". This is the reason you should avoid writing function like your `{{value()}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnPush change detector gets triggered in a couple of other situations other than changes in component Input() references, it also gets triggered for:

- if a component event handler gets triggered
- if an observable linked to the template via the async pipe emits a new value

https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/